# Partial "ON DELETE SET NULL" on composite FK

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I have a set of tables in a PostgreSQL database, call them `employee`, `corporation`, and `account`.  `corporation` has a foreign key to `account` (an "account" is a "business account", spanning one or more corporations, not a "user account" like one would use to log into a system), and `employee` has a composite foreign key to `corporation` and a foreign key to `account` (it has two columns: `corporation_id` and `account_id`; the foreign key to `corporation` uses both columns).

If an `employee`'s parent `corporation` row is deleted, I would like its `corporation_id` column's value to be set to `NULL`, but the `account_id` column should keep its value.

The idea being that an employee must "belong" to an account (so `employee.account_id` is `NOT NULL`), and can be assigned to any (or none) corporation within that account.  If a corporation is removed, any employees assigned to it should be un-assigned (`employee.corporation_id` set to `NULL`), but they should still "belong" to the account (`employee.account_id` should keep its value).

`ON DELETE SET NULL` on the foreign key to `corporation (id, account_id)` would set both `corporation_id` and `account_id` to `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still interested there is a third workaround:

1. First, create a foreign key constraint for just corporation_id `FOREIGN KEY (corporation_id) REFERENCES corporation(id) ON DELETE SET NULL`.
2. Secondly, create another foreign key constraint for the composite key `FOREIGN KEY (corporation_id, account_id) REFERENCES corporation(id, account_id)` only this time without the `ON DELETE`.

Note that the order in which the constraints are created matters! Because the second constraint defaults to `NO ACTION` an error is only raised if any referencing rows still exist when the constraint is checked. However, because our first constraint sets the corporation_id to `NULL` the referencing row is no longer present and everything works.

Comment: Thanks Kwakel -- this was a huge life saver. Constraints are executed in the order they are created.

However, if you dump a schema it will not create the schema it will not create constraints in the same order they were originally created. Nor is there any way to see what order they were created in.

We had huge headache with our newly created databases from the schema dump behaving differently than production, and the constraints order for a composite key was the issue!

As far as I can tell, this is completely undocumented. So thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Seems postgresql can not handle this.

I can think of 2 workarounds if you just need something which does the job:

- With additional table for the join between employee and corporation:

  1. create a table having the fields **employee_id, corporation_id, account_id**.
  2. foreign keys **(employee_id, account_id)** ref **employee** and **(corporation_id, account_id)** ref **corporation** with DELETE CASCADE
  3. if employee is required to be in one corporation only - add unique constraint on (employee_id, account_id)
  4. at the end corporation_id from employee table is not going to be used
- Or remove account_id from the join and use a trigger to validate that the corporation account_id is same as employee account_id

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding an extra column to `employee` (`current_account_id`), which is used for the foreign key to `corporation`, with `DELETE SET NULL`, and a check constraint for `current_account_id = account_id`.  Only that messed with cascading `id` changes: if `account.id` changed, it cascaded to `employee.account_id` (via `employee`'s foreign key to `account`) and `employee.current_account_id` (via `employee`'s foreign key to `corporation`, via `corporation`'s foreign key to `account`), and at some point they were different (they're obviously not updated atomically), and it violated the check constraint, which PostgreSQL does not allow to be deferrable.  So I changed it to a constraint trigger, which raises `check_constraint` if the values are different, and *is* deferrable (and initially deferred).